# Bar Chart spacing power BI visuals

Tags: powerbi

Good afternoon community,

I am struggling with the latest PBI interface and the visual for a bar chart.  The current settings and all that I have manipulated leave a great deal of white space and an unpleasing visual.
Power BI screen shot
[image]

I dont like all of the unneeded white space to the right and left of the chart, I also cannot figure out how to make the labels appear under the columns.  Here is more what I would like it to look like from excel...

[image]

The below is much more visually appealing but the excel interface is 1990 - never.  I need power BI to be closer to the view from excel.

I would attach the sample pbix but I cannot find instructions for that.  If anyone wants the example pbix to help with this issue please instruct me how to attach the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a clustered column chart, and you have used a categorization in the `legend` field instead of the `x-axis` field.

Here is the same chart using the same `COUNT` measure and the `VAR` categorization column. The left plot (which is what you apparently want) is what you get if you use either a clustered or stacked column chart, but without any categorization in the `legend` field. The right plot shows what you have now, where you have used the categorization in the `legend` field instead of `x-axis` field.

[image]

The left plot is configured like so:

[image]

Comment: None of the other visuals provide the type of output described in the above question.  Everything I have read from MS states it is not an option available in any of their charts, all of those posts are years old so does it seem like MS has not addressed this poor visual then?

Comment: You are not correct - I have booted up Power BI service in parental leave to improve my answer (which was not entirely correct either).